# nginx/plesk, nodejs+apache - rooting

Tags: apache, nginx, plesk, parallels

facts:
-ubuntu 
-plesk 11.0.9
-node.js/apache
-nginx

i want to run node/apache on the same server, 
so i thought nginx wld be the right way

so i installed nginx via plesk

the problem is that i dont find any fitting tutorial/ i don't even know which data to edit to get the problem solved

the setting should be easy -

```
subdomA.dom.com => apache
subdomB.dom.com => node
```

so i just need a simple if or whatever that changes the port either to apache or to node

sth like

```
if(subdom)
    if(subdomA)
         changePort 1111 (apache)
    else if(subdomB)
         changePort 2222 (node)
else
   changePort 1111 (apache)
```

Comment: u using plesk??? do you still need help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is Plesk extension which allows to run Node applications.
http://ext.plesk.com/packages/28f799af-1ff4-4bb8-9c87-a04f0f23d32e-jxcore-support